# Filling forms automatically in Chromium

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

I'm attemping to make a Kiosk style display with the Raspberry Pi. At first, I used kweb3 for this, but as it had very little info available I switched to Chromium. However, I am unable to find info on how to fill out a form on page load.

I was going to use xdotools, but apparently it had some potential issues with this.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Tampermonkey is very popular to do thing on a webpage after it has loaded. The API is simple javascript/jquery basically that runs after the page loaded and doesnt care about cross domain policies etc. But you have to install it and the scripts.